# Can not move an item task from a Public Folder to another public folder, Outlook posts a new Post instead in the second Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I try to move an item from the Public Folder it resides in, to another Public Folder, then the item does not move. Instead there is a new Post created in the new Folder which only takes the Subject of the item.

It happens similarly when trying to copy a task item (either by Drag  and Drop or  by Right hand mouse click menu). There is a new Post that appears in the new Folder, and no item is being copied. I do not want this. I want to move or copy the item.

The new post looks like this:

[image]

I tried this, but I get an error message:

[image]

[image]

I have got "Owner" rights on the working folder. What am I missing?

Thank you so much.